# Template type deduction in container initialisation

Tags: c++

I understand that a template type parameter can be defaulted, however, this doesn't work when I attempt to construct a `std::vector` without supplying the template argument:

```
#include<vector>

template <typename Int = int>
struct integer{
    Int i;
};

int main(){

    integer num;

    std::vector<integer> vec;

    return 0;
}
```

This code returns a type value mismatch ([compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/KbEseqfz3)). Is it possible to fix this without writing `std::vector<integer<int>>`

Comment: `std::vector<integer<>>`?

Comment: Oh yes that works. I was hoping for a solutions which doesn't affect `std::vector<integer> vec` but I'm guessing that's not possible. Thank you though!

Comment: @DanielMeilakyou you don't *want* a solution which will work with `std::vector<integer>`, if `integer` is a template template argument. You have to be specific about those things, because you **can** have a template `my_vector<integer>`, that **will** work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a function with a default parameter:

```
 int foo(int bar=0);
```

To call this function you still have to write:

```
 int n=foo();
```

attempting to write `int n=foo;` will not work, of course. For the same reason if your template's parameters are defaulted you still have to use

```
  integer<>
```

to instantiate the template instead of

```
  integer
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an alias `integer_t` for `interger<>` using [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

```
template <typename Int = int>
struct integer{
    Int i;
};
using integer_t = integer<>;

int main(){
   std::vector<integer_t> vec; // No error.
}
```

The reason why `std::vector<integer>` did not work is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70235560/12416453).

Comment: I always forget about `using`, that is another good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a wrapper that accepts template template parameter (read below):

```
template <template <typename> class TT, 
         typename T = int>
using my_vector = std::vector<TT<T>>;

my_vector<integer> vec{}; // works
my_vector<integer, long> vecLong{}; // using non-default type
```

---

Templates have different types of *template parameters*:
Each parameter in a parameter-list may be:

a non-type template parameter;
a type template parameter;
a template template parameter.

```
template <typename>
struct with_type_parameter{};

template <template <typename> class>
struct with_template_template_parameter{};
```

So, there is an **explicit** difference for compiler between your `integer<>` and `integer`.

- The first one is a *type* explicitly instantiated from a template parameter.
- The second one is a *template template*.

So, when you instantiate a class template `std::vector` with a *template template* `integer` instead of a *type* `integer<>` for an argument, you get the error you have. Because **these two things are different** for class templates.

However, there is a different behavior fo function templates, since they are allowed for overloading.

Here is an example for you: https://godbolt.org/z/cbnss17aj

```
template <typename>
struct with_typename{};

// can't have that. class template can only be specialized when declared
// template <template <typename> class>
// struct with_typename{}; 

#include <iostream>

template <typename>
void with_typename_fn()
{
    std::cout << "type" << std::endl;
}

// perfectly fine, since function template overloading is allowed in C++
template <template <typename> class>
void with_typename_fn()
{
    std::cout << "template template" << std::endl;
}

template <typename>
struct non_defaulted{};

template <typename = int>
struct defaulted{};

int main()
{
    with_typename_fn<int>(); // ok
    with_typename_fn<non_defaulted>(); // also ok
    with_typename_fn<defaulted>(); // also ok, but will resolve to template template specialization!
}
```

Output:

```
type
template template
template template
```

Comment: I was stuck trying to understand what `template <template <typename> class>` meant and at almost the same time you edited your answer I finally realized what it is. I had wanted to use this a long time ago when making a templated print function for `std::list<T>` or `std::vector<T>`. I think I only ended up writing a `std::vector` version at the time. I'll go back an implement that now.

Comment: @DanielMeilak there us a lot you can do with templates in meta programming. For once, you can use `template <template <typename...> class ContainerT>` as a parameter to customize a container that will be used in your template implementation. They can also be defaulted.